# Problemas al abrir el simulador de IOS ... Tengo una máquina virtual bajo windows10 con virtualBox y he instalado IOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, virtualbox, emulación

Estoy abriendo el simulador de iPhone 8 (13.5) bajo un IOS Catalina montado en un virtualBox cuyo host tiene windows 10 y me da el siguiente error al intentar abrirlo...

Springboard se ha cerrado inesperadamente.
Pulse reiniciar ...

Y este es el estado del error que me muestra si le doy a ver detalles ...

Process:               SpringBoard [746]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:            SpringBoard
Version:               1.0 (50)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [494]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [477]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-06-01 11:49:43.179 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F96)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        9ACCF7A2-E5CE-310F-A9E0-7DB784FE740C

Time Awake Since Boot: 290 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
....

### NO PUDE PASAR TODO EL MENSAJE POR FALTA DE BYTES

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=773.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=773.3M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=578.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=578.2M(100%)

```
                            VIRTUAL   REGION
```

REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Foundation                           4K        1 
Image IO                          9876K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           166.2M       24 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        8 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)           4100K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                  128K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M       11 
Stack                             13.1M       12 
VM_ALLOCATE                        420K        3 
__DATA                            17.2M      587 
__DATA_CONST                      69.2M      580 
__DATA_DIRTY                        11K       16 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       323.8M        8 
__OBJC_RO                         40.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2144K        1 
__TEXT                           449.5M      591 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                       31.9M        7 
shared memory                       24K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.5G     1862 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.2G     1862

Model: iMac11,3, BootROM VirtualBox, 3 processors, 3,7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f35
Graphics: spdisplays_display, 5 MB
Memory Module: Bank 0/DIMM 0, 8 GB, DRAM, 1600 MHz, innotek GmbH, -
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: VBOX HARDDISK, 85,9 GB
Serial ATA Device: VBOX CD-ROM, 8,91 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB Tablet
USB Device: USB Keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus:

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné seteando esto desde el cmd en modo Administrador:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```

Encontré la información en este lado:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367695/virtualbox-macos-catalina-springboard-quit-unexpectedly